# What to do when complete cases vs. imputed cases and train vs. test disagree?

Tags: cross-validation, survival, missing-data, multiple-imputation

In a fairly complex survival analysis case with considerable missing data, I split the data set into training and testing and ran models for both complete cases and imputed cases (I used multiple imputation).

Although I ran the same model for all 4 cases, the parameter estimates and p values for some variables disagree.

I am looking for any reference or guidance saying which set of parameter estimates is best to accept, given that I will note concerns about the whole project.